# CasperJS login form wait success

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I try login in the page:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://sprashivai.ru/', function() {
    this.click('#signin_link');

    this.capture('foo.jpg', undefined, {
        format: 'jpg',
        quality: 75
    });

    this.fillSelectors('form', {
        '#signin_username' : 'admin@*****',
        '#signin_pass' : '*****'
    }, true);

    casper.then(function() {
        this.capture('foo_2.jpg', undefined, {
            format: 'jpg',
            quality: 75
        });
    });

    casper.thenOpen(function() {
        this.capture('foo_3.jpg', undefined, {
            format: 'jpg',
            quality: 75
        });
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        this.capture('foo_4.jpg', undefined, {
            format: 'jpg',
            quality: 75
        });
    });

    this.waitForSelector("#top_nq_badge",
        function pass () {
            test.pass("Found #top_nq_badge");
        },
        function fail () {
            test.fail("Did not load element #top_nq_badge");
        },
        20000 // timeout limit in milliseconds
    );
});


casper.run();
```

I know that after login I can see element #top_nq_badge, but waitForSelector not work for me.
How I can login with CasperJS on the page?

I run the script:
$ casperjs secr.js
And it nothing print, script success worked without errors.

foo_3.jpg and foo_4.jpg files not created by script.
But my foo.jpg and foo_2.jpg screenshots:

[image: foo.jpg]

[image: foo_2.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `test` variable, to catch an error about it, you need to use `.on('error'` callback, Loading of the selector `#top_nq_badge` is very slowly.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    waitTimeout: 5000,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4',
    viewportSize:{width: 1600, height: 900}
})
.on('error', function(msg) {
    this.echo('Error: ' + msg, "ERROR");
})
.on('remote.message', function(msg) {this.echo('The error from evaluate: ' + msg, "ERROR");})
.start('http://sprashivai.ru/', function() {
    this
    .click('#signin_link');
    this.wait(0,function(){var i=0;
    function snap(){i++;casper.capture('foo_'+i+'.jpg', undefined,{format: 'jpg',quality: 75});if(i<4){setTimeout(snap,1000)}}snap();
    })
    .fillSelectors('form', {
        '#signin_username' : '<login_here>',
        '#signin_pass' : '<pass_here>'
    }, true)
    .waitForSelector("#top_nq_badge",
    function success() {
        this
            .echo('logged in!', 'INFO')
            .capture('in.png')
    },
    function fail(){
        this
            .capture('failed.png')
            .echo('failed to login', 'ERROR');
    })
})
.run()
```

Comment: [foo_0.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnREpOeVVjdFc4eWc) | [foo_1.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnSmI0a2NucEZRZUk) | [foo_2.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnOVBYSFE1MTBkLVE) | [foo_3.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnYURFMXlmMnlhMGc) | [foo_4.jpg](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_tqnSHhFPBnZGliRFFQc0Viams)

Comment: [Choose UserAgent Here!](https://github.com/dillbyrne/random-agent-spoofer/blob/master/data/json/useragents.json)

Comment: Yes, loading this selector is very slowly, any ideas?

Comment: it seems, there is no way to avoid it, i've tried with many selectors, but it has no effect.